# multiple mixins and __init__ methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, mixins

Say I have a base class (MyBase) which has an `__init__` method

I also have 2 mixins. Each of these mixins has a single attribute, and a couple of methods, but none of the methods or attributes are common in the two mixins.

MyBaseClass, mixin1, and mixin2 all inherit from object

I want to derive a class (MyRealClass) from the mixins (mixin1 and mixin2) and from MyBase.

From what I saw on MRO, the correct definition of MyRealClass would be

```
class MyRealClass(mixin1, mixin2, MyBase):
```

MyRealClass has a do_init method (I want to control when I initialize certain parts of the class, but MyBase has an `__init__` method.

My question is, in the mixins, should I have an `__init__` method in them?

Can you explain why they should? I don't need to do any work in the init for either mixin for my class.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `__init__` will be automatically invoked on your `MyRealClass` objects when they are created. Then, the function call is treated according to MRO: first, if `MyRealClass` defines `__init__`, it will be called, otherwise the interpreter will search for `__init__` in the parent classes: `Mixin1`, `Mixin2`, and, finally, in `MyBase`. This means that `MyRealClass` does not need any `__init__` method.

If you choose to implemet `MyRealClass.__init__` at some point, make sure to call `super(MyRealClass, self).__init__()` or you will shadow the `MyBase` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no point overriding a method if you're not doing anything in it. Just let it automatically inherit the superclass method.